# limit urllib getcode to specific time, to avoid freeze

Tags: python, web, urllib, freeze

I have written some code, to do to get some information from an rss feed, and it's working great.
However, the feed i am working with, seems to very unreliable, and is often down. Therefore i have added a feature to check if the site is up, and if it isn't, then wait a minute to try again.

I noticed today, that it have a tendency to freeze up, and i have to restart the program to make it work again.

My guess is, that it has problems getting the '200' from the website.

How can i set a 'time limit' for how long it should try to get sitestatus, before just skipping?

I use python 2.7

here is the code i have:

```
try:
urllib.urlopen(sites).getcode() == 200
# more code here
except:
t = FindSites(sites)
print 'Failed to connect to ' + t
```

thanks

EDIT:
Thanks. Trying the code, and it should work now

Answer (score 1):

You could use [urllib2.urlopen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen), which supports a timeout:

> urllib2.urlopen(url[, data][, timeout])

Comment: @Dennis Olsen, is there anything else I can do to make this answer more acceptable to you?